# How do I get the size of open windows?

Tags: windows-vista, window

I want know the size (width and height) in pixels of a window that an application has opened. What's the simplest/quickest way for me to get it? Without doing any programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an especially retarded way but this is what I used to do (it includes the Windows frame):

1. Press ALT + PrtSc (Print screen)
2. Open photoshop or fireworks and create new file

They usually default to the size of whats in your clipboard. You can probably do something similar with another program.

Comment: +1 A good way if you only want to do it occasionally.

Comment: Good answer. I would upvote it, if only I had 15 reputation. *hint hint*. :)

Comment: Works the same way using Gnome, Debian linux and Gimp.

Comment: Alt+Prtsc, Win+r, "mspaint", crtl+v, ctrl+e. Keyboard only. No download necessary. You win.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the free version of [FastStone Capture](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html) to capture the window (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PtintScr</kbd>) which is then displayed in its editor with the size shown in the status bar...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux, just start up any screen grabbing program (KSnapshot for example), select new snapshot to be a "selected region" and draw a rectangle with the mouse over a window. It show you the size of the region you marked.

If you want it more precisely or if you want to use a bash script to capture sizes, there are different methods depending on the DE you use and on the compositing manager (if any).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Windows Vista (see tag)